# Change WooCommerce Add to Cart messages for a product category in Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to change the Add to Cart messages based on categories for the "add_to_cart" shortcode.

I can change it on the product pages and archive pages using below code. But the shortcode in posts/pages always has the "Buy Now" message.

```
//Add to cart - change the message in single product pages

add_filter( 'add_to_cart_text','woo_custom_single_add_to_cart_text' );

add_filter('woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text','woo_custom_single_add_to_cart_text' );

function woo_custom_single_add_to_cart_text() {

    if( has_term( array('Online Courses'), 'product_cat' ) )
         $text = __( 'Enrol Now', 'woocommerce' );
    else
        $text = __( 'Buy Now', 'woocommerce' );

    return $text; 
}


//Add to cart - change message in Archive pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text','woo_custom_product_add_to_cart_text' );

function woo_custom_product_add_to_cart_text() {

    if( has_term( array('Online Courses'), 'product_cat' ) )
                $text = __( 'Enrol Now', 'woocommerce' );
    else
        $text = __( 'Buy Now', 'woocommerce' );
    return $text;
}
```

I expect when I include the '[add_to_cart id="4848"]' in any page/post, it should show "Enrol Now" for this category.

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_single_add_to_cart_text' ); // 2.1 +

function woo_custom_single_add_to_cart_text() {
if (has_term( array('uncategorized'), 'product_cat' ))
     $text = __( 'My Button Text', 'woocommerce' );
return  $text;

}
```

can you try with slug of the categories???

Comment: In my case, when I load the button in a page/post using the shortcode [add_to_cart id="4848"], it shows the else part text (Buy Now). But in product single page and archive page, the product correctly shows 'enrol now'.

Comment: In the category pages also, it shows "Enrol Now". the shortcode only has the issue.